# can't access external drive (Ubuntu on imac / can "see" the external imac drive on Ubuntu 'Files', but can't authenticate)

Tags: hard-drive, samba, vmware, mac, external-hdd

First, apologies in advance if my question has an obvious solution and I am simply too dense to figure it out. That said, here goes:

- Recently installed Ubuntu 20.etc on VMware Fusion / imac. No problems with that.
- I can "see" external drives plugged into the imac in the Ubuntu 'Files' app.
- 'Files' app can access the imac home directory on the MacIntosh HDD drive without any authentication.
- Other / external drives appear in 'Files', but clicking on them results in an authentication window ("Password required for share blahBlahBlah on imac.local" etc.).
- Authentication window doesn't allow anonymous user.
- Authentication window doesn't allow the one 'Registered User' on the system, to access the drive.

My guess is that this problem has something to do with Samba configuration. However, I am quickly confused by all of the information available online, and don't want to accidentally make an even bigger mess while trying to sort out the original problem. This problem seems like it should have a simple solution, and I believe I am making it unnecessarily complicated while trying to solve it.

All I need to do is very simple: Read / write files in Ubuntu from an external drive connected to an imac running Ubuntu in a VMware Fusion environment. Any help towards a simple solution of this problem is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me that Samba is involved in this question. Is this link relevant to the "external drives" you are talking about: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1021853

Comment: thank you for your reply. I followed the information in the link you provided, but after making changes, received the following message:

"The device <driveName> was unable to connect to its ideal host controller."

Comment: Ubuntu 20.etc this is not any version of Ubuntu that exists.

Comment: Just a suggestion but I think you will get a faster answer by asking this in the vmware forum. Did a quick search and found this based on your error message: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/USB-3-0-support/td-p/1288281

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about this being more of a VMware problem than an Ubuntu problem. Thanks for you help, and for clarifying things.